# php code for shopping cart

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

"Hi, I have a problem here, I want to know how I can put a condition in this code if I want to set the button disabled if the quantity is below or equal to 0. I typed the code below. Thanks hope you can help me."

```
<?php
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT product_code, product_name, product_desc, product_img_name, QtyOnHand, product_price FROM allitems where id <= 4");
if($results){
$products_item = '<ul class="products">';
while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
{
$products_item .= <<<EOT
<li class="product">
<form method="post" action="../../cart_update.php">
<div class="product-content"><h3>{$obj->product_name}</h3>
<div class="product-thumb"><img src="../../images/{$obj->product_img_name}" class="img"></div>
<div class="product-info">
Price {$currency}{$obj->product_price}
<fieldset>
<label>
Quantity Left: {$obj-> QtyOnHand}<br>
<span>Quantity</span>
<input type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" name="product_qty" value="1" />
</label>
</fieldset>
<input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="{$obj->product_code}" />
<input type="hidden" name="type" value="add" />
<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="{$current_url}" />
<div align="center">
<div align="center">
<button type="submit" class="add_to_cart" name="add_button" >Add</button></div>
</div></div>
</form>
</li>
EOT;
}
$products_item .= '</ul>';
echo $products_item;
}
?>
```

Comment: Why dont you use html `min` attribute and set it to 1 so that quantity will never go beyond 1. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_min.asp

Comment: You still need to validate input on server. For client-side, use javascript: bind a function that checks the input value to `onchange` or similar event of the same input. Within this function toggle the button state based on the check result.

Comment: Sorry, but what I mean is that if the Quantity On Hand (QtyOnHand) is less than or equal to zero, the button will be disabled.

Comment: That's what B-and-P says, but, not sure why, I think you are new to programming ;)

Comment: hehe yeah i'm just a student and I am currently working on my capstone project,

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
<input type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" {if($obj->QtyOnHand<1, 'disabled="disabled"')} name="product_qty" value="1" />
```